# Orientación visualizar datos - pasos y consejos con un dataframe pequeño

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

quisiera pedir su amable colaboracion para orientarme para hacer mi primer proyecto, yo hasta ahora habia utilizado dataframes ya limpios para hacer operaciones básicas y ahora me enfrento a mi primera base de datos pero no se como abordarla, ya he cambiado el tipo de datos de las columnas a enteros para hacer operaciones y una en string, estas son las columnas:

```
df1.info()

out:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 28 entries, 0 to 27
Data columns (total 9 columns):
#   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
0   CLASE APORTANTE  28 non-null     object
1   ANO-2014         28 non-null     int64 
2   ANO-2015         28 non-null     int64 
3   ANO-2016         28 non-null     int64 
4   ANO-2017         28 non-null     int64 
5   ANO-2018         28 non-null     int64 
6   ANO-2019         28 non-null     int64 
7   ANO-2020         28 non-null     int64 
8   ANO-2021         28 non-null     int64 
dtypes: int64(8), object(1)
memory usage: 2.1+ KB
```

Ahora, el problema que tengo o que no se como solucionar es que no se como procesar los datos o como manipularlos, o como deberia hacerlo, porque en esta base da datos, la CLASE APORTANTE tiene varios ingresos de los años del 2014 al 2021, pero pues esa información se separa por columnas y habia visto que en otras bases de datos ea información se separa normalmente se hacia una columna años, y una columna valores, y así se metia todo en esas dos columnas, esta es la vista de las 3 primeras filas del dataframe mostrando solo tres columnas, pero el resto de años serían iguales, los años representan los ingresos en impuestos y clase de aportantes los negocios que los pagaron

```
CLASE APORTANTE   ANO-2014       ANO-2015        
Hoteles           8258014655     9370587368
A.Viajes          2370773024     2605481965
D.Nauticos        7606910        8940064
```

Entonces a mi me gustaría poder generar un gráfico en el que aparecieran cada uno de las clases aportantes por año en un solo grafico, o reducir el grafico a los que más aportan a 5, y luego poderlo hacer por todos los años y ver el crecimiento, pero pues pense en usar el elemento

```
a =df1.groupby(["ANO-2014","ANO-2015"])["CLASE APORTANTE"].value_counts()
```

Pero creo que no es así porque es casi la misma información pero al revés. Agradeceria sus aportes porque he visto como conceptos y estadística, pero no se como ordenar mi conjunto de datos para poder hacer graficos y visualizar, gracias.

Comment: Para el eje de las x debes poner el año y para el eje y debes colocar los valores de la columna y así para cada `CLASE APORTANTE`. Empieza por eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) y cualquier gráfica (Para el ejemplo voy a utilizar [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

El `dataframe` que utilizo en el ejemplo es el mismo que pusiste en tu pregunta pero aumenté dos ceros en los valores de D.Nauticos para que la gráfica fuera visible (Nota: estoy utilizando la columna "CLASE APORTANTE" como índice):

```
                ANO-2014    ANO-2015
CLASE APORTANTE     
Hoteles         8258014655  9370587368
A.Viajes        2370773024  2605481965
D.Nauticos      760691000   894006400
```

Luego utilizo el método `melt()` para generar dos columnas `variable` que serían los años y otra `value` que son los valores y con el argumento `ignore_index=False` conservamos los índices originales

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, ignore_index = False)
```

Al imprimir `df1` obtenemos:

```
                variable    value
CLASE APORTANTE     
Hoteles         ANO-2014    8258014655
A.Viajes        ANO-2014    2370773024
D.Nauticos      ANO-2014    760691000
Hoteles         ANO-2015    9370587368
A.Viajes        ANO-2015    2605481965
D.Nauticos      ANO-2015    894006400
```

Luego únicamente graficamos, para obtener todos los datos en una gráfica puedes utilizar el argumento `hue` para mostrar las leyendas

```
ax = sns.barplot(data = df1, x = 'variable', y = 'value', hue = df1.index)
```

Esto crea la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica con todas las clases juntas]

Si desearas graficar clase por clase es muy sencillo, del `dataframe` que creamos con `melt()` puedes seleccionar cualquier clase con el método `loc()`

```
df2 = df1.loc['Hoteles']
```

Y graficar de la misma manera

```
ax = sns.barplot(data = df2, x = 'variable', y = 'value', hue = df2.index)
```

Esto crea la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica clase hoteles]

**NOTA:** No mencionas en tu pregunta algún tipo de gráfica en específico pero yo recomiendo el módulo `seaborn`, de igual forma para mostrar la gráfica, cambiar el título, tamaño, colores, etcétera, tendrás que investigar un poco ya que el objetivo de la pregunta era como organizar los datos para graficarlos fácilmente y eso se obtiene con el método `melt()`

Comment: quisiera preguntarte como puedo organizar la tablita que sale por el hue, porque en mi dataframe son 28 aportantes, y queda ya sobre el gráfico, yo podría limitar el número de clase aportante (df2.index) a los que tengan los valores más grandes, o podría acomodar a algun costado esa tabla?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Podrías crear una nueva pregunta e incluir lo que has intentado al respecto? Recuerda que el objetivo del sitio es que las personas muestren su esfuerzo por resolver sus propias preguntas. Si esta respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas

Comment: Lo siento, no se como aceptarla, voy a mirar un tutorial y la acepto. Gracias.